# How can I increase a value by 5% monthly using a while loop?

Tags: python, finance

I'm attempting to take a starting balance and increase the value by 5% each month.  I then want to feed this new balance back into the equation for the next month.  I've attempted to do this using a while loop but it doesn't seem to be feeding the new balance back in.

I'm using 60 months (5 years) for the equation but this can be altered

```
counter = 1
balance = 1000
balance_interest = balance * .05

while counter <= 60:
    new_monthly_balance = (balance + balance_interest)*(counter/counter)
    print(new_monthly_balance)
    balance = new_monthly_balance
    counter += 1
```

Comment: `counter/counter` will always be 1. What are you *trying* to multiply by?

Comment: `*(counter/counter)` will either do nothing (if `counter` is not zero), or make a mess (if it is, which will never happen in this snippet). Also you precalculate your 5%, but presumably you want to add 5% of whatever the balance is _then_. So `new_monthly_balance = balance * (1 + balance_interest)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never change `balance_interest` in the loop.

What do you intend to do with `*(counter/counter)`?  This merely multiplies by 1.0, which is a no-op.

```
while counter <= 60:
    balance *= 1.05
    print(balance)
    counter += 1
```

Better yet, since you know how many times you want to iterate, use a `for`:

```
for month in range(60):
    balance *= 1.05
    print(balance)
```

BTW, just what sort of finance has a constant 5% *monthly* increase???

Comment: Thank you!  I'm new to Python and it's my first programming language so I'm still trying to understand the logic.

In regards to the finance question, I was trying to model increases in my portfolio for day trading assuming an average of 5% monthly returns